# java.lang.NullPointerException upon file I/O

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner

When I run the code, I get an error. The strange thing is when I change `files.getTimeScore();` to `files.getLineScore();`, it executes without errors. However, these functions are almost identical to each other.

When I run the `getTimeScore()` method from a main in the `FileIO` class, then it works fine.

#### Errors

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at tetris.FileIO.loadHighscores(FileIO.java:52)
at tetris.FileIO.getTimeScores(FileIO.java:31)
at tetris.HighScores.<init>(HighScores.java:39)
at tetris.Menu$2.actionPerformed(Menu.java:74)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

#### Code

Highscores class

```
public HighScores(){
    // init A
    super("Highscores");
    c=getContentPane();
    test = new String[100][2];
    files = new FileIO();

    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    test = files.getTimeScores();
    timeTable = new JTable(test,timeTitles );
    test = files.getLineScores();
    lineTable = new JTable(test,lineTitles );
```

FileIO class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FileIO {
    private File file;
    private Scanner filescScanner, lineScanner;
    private Writer fileWriter, lineWriter;
    private String[][] data;

    public FileIO () {
        data = new String[100][2];
    }

    public String[][] getLineScores(){
        return this.loadHighscores(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("LineHighscores.txt"));
    }

    public String[][] getTimeScores(){
        return this.loadHighscores(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("TimeHighscores.txt"));
    }

    public String[][] loadHighscores( InputStream resourceStream){
        int x=0;
        String test = "";

        filescScanner = new Scanner(resourceStream);

        while(filescScanner.hasNextLine()&& x<100) {
            lineScanner = new Scanner(filescScanner.nextLine());
            lineScanner.useDelimiter("-/-");

            data[x][0]=lineScanner.next();//name
            data[x][1]=lineScanner.next();//data
            x++;
        }
        lineScanner.close();
        filescScanner.close();
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: which is line 52 in `FileIO` ?

Comment: as the answers say, when your while loop get's skipped because of it's condition being false, `lineScanner` will be `null` and calling a method on `null` will result in a NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't test those files can be accessed. i.e. if `resourceStream` is null.

Using this approach is not idea as you cannot easily update these files if you want add a high score.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your lineScanner is null. Can't see where you intialize it in FileIO.
You only intialize it in the while-clause. 
So if your File is empty, it is still null when you are trying to close it.

Comment: nop, cause when i only use getLineHighscore(); in stead og getTimeHighscore(); it works fine

Answer (score 0):

line scanner is null for TimeHighscores.txt file. So it means that the while loop was not executed - not even once.